# Change date format on typescript to send data as DateTimeOffset to backend (C#) side

Tags: c#, date, momentjs

I want to send date info to backend side. But I couldn't find the true date format to send it.

I have date as a string. I want to convert this string to another date format to send it backend and backend will take it as a DateTimeOffset.

My string :

```
_finishDateTime: "2021-11-12T00:00:00"
```

Expected format from backend side:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can mention the format you have on your client-side. In addition to that, I think you don't need to convert it to another date format like you are planning to do before you send it to the server. You can send the string data to the server and do the conversion in the server itself.

Comment: Your post does not seem to have a question. Please add one.

Answer (score 0):

The string Representation of a DateTimeOffset is like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff+xx:xx` with the offset part (+xx:xx) being the diference with UTC time (note that the + could be a minus '-')

Example: 2021-12-23T13:50:45.200+02:00

Also if you are passing a UTC time you can send `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` (Z = Zulu aka UTC)

Comment: I added my format and expected format into my question.

Comment: The _Expected format from backend_ you posted didn't seems a C# format, if your backend is any sort of c# API, send it as a string in the format I posted